# Can't setup the permitAll() mather

Tags: java, spring-security, h2-console

I try to setup endpoint `/h2-console` for `permitAll()` to get access to the h2-console without login.

My security config:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public SCryptPasswordEncoder sCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return SCryptPasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_8();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
    //                .anyRequest().permitAll() < -- with this line works, so any other FilterChain does not exist in the project. I swear
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main", true)
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

}
```

I also will put all other configs for any case:

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationConfig {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private JpaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private SCryptPasswordEncoder sCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        CustomUserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        switch (user.secureUser().getAlgorithm()) {
            case BCRYPT:
                return checkPassword(user, password, bCryptPasswordEncoder);
            case SCRYPT:
                return checkPassword(user, password, sCryptPasswordEncoder);
            default:
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }
    }

    private Authentication checkPassword(CustomUserDetails user, String rawPassword, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        if (encoder.matches(rawPassword, user.getPassword())) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

But when I try to get to the `localhost:8080/h2-console` I have redirected to the `/login` page

---

UPD:

Spring security logs:

> c.e.springinactions.SequrityApplication  : Started SequrityApplication in 11.758 seconds (process running for 12.623)
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /h2-console
> o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
> o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/h2-console?continue to session
> o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
> o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that another security filter in the chain is overriding this configuration.

You can try adding the following code to your `securityFilterChain` method to explicitly allow access to the H2 console:

```java
.httpBasic().disable()
.csrf().disable()
.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/h2-console*", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
    .and()
.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
.headers()
    .frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

This will disable basic authentication and CSRF protection for the H2 console, and allow all requests to the `/h2-console/**` path to be permitted without authentication. It also sets the frame options to `sameOrigin` to prevent issues with the console not displaying properly.

Note that it's important to keep the H2 console secured in production environments, as it provides direct access to your database.

You add this configuration into the `securityFilterChain` testing if you are test profile/environment...

Comment: Thanks.
Any another SecurityFilterChain isn't exist, but this is helped: `.httpBasic().disable()
.csrf().disable()`

Comment: I am sorry, I am not noticed I not deleted `anyRequest.permitAll()`  function - this is a reason why /h2-console endpoint was answering.  Currently still not working

Comment: Okay, i edited the code o answer, you can try again!